# What are the effects of steroids taken for asthma on the throat and vocal abilities?

Tags: voice, health

I have asthma and I was wondering what are the effects of steroid inhalers taken for asthma on the throat and vocal abilities?

Answer (score 1):

According to the MayoClinic's [website](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/corticosteroid-inhalation-route/side-effects/drg-20070533), side effects of inhaled corticosteroids for treatment of asthma, in the proper dosage is very safe and relatively side effect-free. Except for rare cases of thrush (a fungal infection in the mouth) and some reports of hoarseness, regular amounts of singing or vocal activity are completely compatible with the medication.

If the drug prevents you from doing things you enjoy or causes you discomfort, you should let your doctor know about it and ask if there's a more appropriate course of action for your situation.